# How can I refresh a Slicer when the data source has changed

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I have a pivot table for a group of employees. I currently have two slicers, first one is for the teams and the second one is for team members (names). My problem is, data source of the team member slicer is a table of which the content changes when one/more teams are selected in the first slicer. I have managed to refresh the second slicer manually by right-click on the slicer -> refresh. Since I have a Worksheet_Change sub for another step of the process, I just wanted to automate the refresh as well. Below is the macro I recorded which did not work when I ran it.

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Selected Sector Partners")).Select
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Selected_Sector_Partners").WorkbookConnection.Refresh
    End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like you would do better to alter your source to include both team and team members with team members to the right of teams. Then ensure slicer set-up to hide items with no data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have found a way to do it through refreshing the pivot table itself. Just taking a longer time though. Putting the team and team member together won’t work because some team members belong to multiple teams and the relationship I had between yearly results tables and team members’ names does not support “Many to Many” relationship. That’s why I created a table for the names to appear just once and used this new dynamic table to creat the relationship. This table was also the data source of the slicer in my question.